# Migration .Net framework to .NET 6 - class library

Tags: dll, .net-6.0

During migration of our existing project targeting .NET framework 4.8 we encountered starnge error:

MC1000 Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' in assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\ref\net6.0\System.Web.dll'.'

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfkQd.png)

Basically we have one big class library targeting net6.0-windows that has been used across multiple different smaller projects.

This class library is compileable as a stanalone porject with no errors, but as soon as we reference it in our WPF project, also targeting same net6.0-windows, we got this error.

Does anyone experiencing sme problem?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: That class is only available in the legacy framework version of System.Web.  Typical porting hazard, you've probably got an assembly that is still targeting the olden framework.

Comment: Is there any way how to find assembly that is referencing it? If I search across entire solution  for "System.Web" I have no referencies found...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found that mixing of ASP.NET components together with WinForm or WPF is not allowed anymore. So solution was to split our library file into two separate DLL assemblies each targeting proper SDK.